# Exception in Release mode only while reflectively creating objects

Tags: c#, exception, reflection, release

My application is failing only when I attempt to launch it in release mode. Debug mode works fine. I am getting an error that reads

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Because this only happens in release, it's been a bit difficult to debug. However, if I uncheck the "Optimize code" checkbox in the project properties, I am able to see an exception thrown in this method:

```
 private static T MakeObject<T>(Type type) where T :class
    {
        //Default reflective behavior to create an instance with an empty constructor
        //
        //*note: .GetConstructor can return null.
        object obj = null;
        T tObj = default(T);
        
        ConstructorInfo ci = type.GetConstructor(TypeInfo.EmptyTypes);

        if (ci != null)
        {
            obj = ci.Invoke(new object[] { /* Empty */});

            tObj = obj as T;
        }

        if (tObj == null)
            throw new InvalidCastException("Fatal error occurred within NavigationService (GetConstructor). Type: " + type.ToString());

        return tObj;
    }
```

on this line:

```
ConstructorInfo ci = type.GetConstructor(TypeInfo.EmptyTypes);
```

The exception reads:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in LWDCloudManager.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might be able either fix this issue, or how to dig deeper and understand why this could be happening in release mode only?

Comment: Is `type` null? If so, it's impossible to tell why from this code alone. Look at the stack when the exception occurs to see who called this method and why the caller passed null.

Comment: So are you interpreting that error to mean that the `type` variable is `null` or that `GetConstructor` returned `null`. To me, it would appear to be the former, but [the latter also appears to be a possibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h93ya84h(v=vs.110).aspx) (see note in return value documentation). Maybe you can try throwing an exception if `type` is `null`?

Comment: The issue is that this problem only occurs in release mode. So I don't have access to the inner exception or to the call stack. However, checking in debug mode, the argument "type" is not being passed in as null.

Comment: What is `TypeInfo.EmptyTypes`? An array of `Type`s? If so, see if you can narrow which type is causing the issue, then supply the definition of that class if possible.

Comment: People who downvote questions without providing an explanation are the worst type of people. Although you may not have access to the exception in the debugger, can you print it (in its entirety) to console or log file?

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I add a try catch and print the exception, it is saying that my argument "type" is null. But when I step through my code in debug mode, it is not null, and it is set to a reference. The problem must be happening before this point somewhere in the code I suppose

Comment: Possible race condition? Things run much slower in debug mode...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered the problem. Actually kind of a stupid problem/oversight by me. Recently my company decided that instead of throwing exceptions in internal methods, we would just use Debug.Asserts, so I went and changed all of them. One of the lines of code ahead of this issue was a debug assert wrapped around a call to a TryGetValue call on a dictionary. Because I was attempting to run in release mode, the debug.assert was not executed, thus the value was not retrieved from the dictionary resulting in a null being passed. Thanks for the help guys

Comment: Might not be the best idea... Now your production releases will still throw if there's a bug, but much later and possibly in a completely unrelated place, making debugging harder unless the exception is easily reproducible. Was it a reaction to "our product crashes too much, can we just remove those throws"?